# How can lists/vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be thought of as functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's written in my linear algebra textbook that $\mathbb{R}^S$ is the set of all possible functions $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$, I fail to see how this applies when $S=2=\lbrace {0,1} \rbrace$ as it's not clear to me how a vector like $(72,15)$ is a function

Comment: I think $2=\{0,1\}$, and then $(72,15)$ represents the function where $f(0)=72$ and $f(1)=15$.

Comment: My comment should answer your question. Is there anything unclear about it?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip If your comment answers the question, you should make it an answer! I’d gladly +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of $\mathbb R^n$ as lists of numbers but you can also think of it as functions $f\colon \{1,\ldots,n\}\to \mathbb R$ where the $j$th coordinate can be regarded as $f(j)$. Then, if $|S|=s$ we have that $\mathbb R^S\cong \mathbb R^s$.

Comment: Small edit - changed $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ since you used $n$ afterwards.

Comment: @Sambo, oops. Thanks.